# can't catch the MapRightTapped message in the MapControl

Tags: uwp

I draw a Ellipse in an MapControl like below, when I set the "Fill" attribute, i can't catch the MapRightTapped message in the MapControl, How can i Do?

```
 <Ellipse  maps:MapControl.Location="{x:Bind CurrentLocation,Mode=OneWay}"
  Fill="#597FACFE"
  Opacity="0.3"
  Stroke="#FF81AEFF"
  StrokeThickness="2"
  Width="50"
  Height="50"
  Margin="50"/>
```

Comment: And how is that related to C? Don't spam tags!

Answer (score 0):

You added the `Ellipse` control to [`MapItemsControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapitemscontrol.aspx) items collection, and with `Fill` property it seems like it will cover the map control that you cannot access the [`MapRightTapped`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.maprighttapped) event. In my opinion, items added to `MapItemsControl` are XAML control collections, they should not be able to listen for map relative event. To resolve this, you can add [`MapElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapelement) collection to [`MapControl.MapElements`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.mapelements) since `MapElement` is inherit from `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps`. For example, the following code is adding a rectangle to the map with color filled but it will not prevent the `MapRightTapped` event handle(you can draw [`Geocircle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geoshapetype) instead ).

```
 private void btnaddpologon_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     double centerLatitude = MapMain.Center.Position.Latitude;
     double centerLongitude = MapMain.Center.Position.Longitude;
     MapPolygon mapPolygon = new MapPolygon();
     mapPolygon.Path = new Geopath(new List<BasicGeoposition>() {
         new BasicGeoposition() {Latitude=centerLatitude+5, Longitude=centerLongitude-1 },
         new BasicGeoposition() {Latitude=centerLatitude-5, Longitude=centerLongitude-1 },
         new BasicGeoposition() {Latitude=centerLatitude-5, Longitude=centerLongitude+1 },
         new BasicGeoposition() {Latitude=centerLatitude+5, Longitude=centerLongitude+1 },
     });
     mapPolygon.ZIndex = 1;
     mapPolygon.FillColor = Colors.Red;
     mapPolygon.StrokeColor = Colors.Blue;
     mapPolygon.StrokeThickness = 3;
     mapPolygon.StrokeDashed = false;
     MapMain.MapElements.Add(mapPolygon);
 }
```

More details about adding the `MapElement` please reference scenario 2 of the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl). But pay attention that **we may not add `MapElement` by binding in XAML**, we may only add them code behind.

Another workaround you can catch the [`RightTapped`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.righttapped) event of `Ellipse`  control, and do the same thing in this event handle as what you did in `MapRightTapped`.

```
<Maps:MapControl
     x:Name="MapMain"    
     MapRightTapped="MapMain_MapRightTapped"  >
     <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapItems">
         <Ellipse
             x:Name="ell"
             ...
             Fill="#597FACFE"                
             Opacity="0.3"  RightTapped="ell_RightTapped">    
         </Ellipse> 
     </Maps:MapItemsControl>
</Maps:MapControl>
```

Code behind:

```
 private void ell_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var input = e.GetPosition(ell);       
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("x:" + input.X + "y:" + input.Y);
 }
```

But this way we cannot get [`MapRightTappedEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.maprighttappedeventargs).